# How to implement linked list with 1 million nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph, linked-list

I recently attended Microsoft Interview.

I was asked to implement linked list with 1 million nodes? How will you access 999999th node?

What is the optimal design strategy and implementation for such a question?

Comment: I can't help thinking immediately "it depends, what for?". Don't answer that at an interview, though. Anyway, you are asking for an "optimal" solution, so... It depends. For an interview, it is much more a bet for what the interviewer expects for the position, rather than an SO issue...

Comment: I will probably question the use of a linkedlist for a 1 million node collection and fail the interview because this is microsoft we are talking about. that said the worst case of the adjacent list when implementing a graph  is a single linked list

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A linked list has fairly few variations, because much variation means it would be something other than a linked list.

You can vary it by having single or double linking. Single linking is where you have a pointer to the head (the first node, A say) which points to B which points to C, etc. To turn that into a double linked list you would also add a link from C to B and B to A.

If you have a double linked list then it's meaningful to retain a pointer to the list tail (the last node) as well as the head, which means accessing the last element is cheap, and elements near the end are cheaper, because you can work backwards or forwards... BUT... you would need to know what you want is at the end of the list... AND at the end of the day a linked list is still just that, and if it is going to get very large and that is a problem because of the nature of its use case, then a storage structure other than a linked list should probably be chosen.

You could hybridise your linked list of course, so you could index it or something for example, and there's nothing wrong with that in theory, but if you index ALL the nodes then the linked list nature is no longer of much value, and if you index only some, then the nodes in between indexed nodes have to be sorted or something so you can find a close node and work towards a target node... probably this would never be optimal and a better data structure should be chosen.

Really a linked list should be used when you don't want to do things like get a specific node, but want to iterate nodes regardless.

Comment: And probably this kind of reasoning was what the interviewer expected, more than a clear solution to the problem

Comment: I agree, I've interviewed plenty of people, and I can think of no other type of answer I could be expecting from a candidate, were I to ask them a question like that.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning about Skip Lists if you are trying to keep the items stored in order (sorted order, insertion order, etc.), which is often the case with very large data sets. Skip Lists are just like linked lists but are instead multi-level with the higher levels skipping half of the nodes (on an average) compared to the lower level linked list.

Answer (score 9):

I have no idea about what I'm going to say, but, here goes:

You could `conceptually` split the list in `sqrt(1000000)` *blocks*, in such a way that you would have "reference pointers" every 1000 elements.

Think of it as having `1000 linked lists` each with `1000 elements` representing your list with `1000000 elements`.

This is what comes to mind!

Comment: Generalize this concept and you get a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

Comment: Cool!! I didnt know about this :)

Comment: Yeah like bucket sort

Answer (score 2):

As Michael said you should present first the two classic variations of linked list. The next thing you should do is ask about insertion, search and deletion patterns.

These patterns will guide you towards a better fit data structure, because **nobody** wants a simple or double linked list with a million nodes.

Answer (score 0):

A doubly circular Linked List with a static counter to point the index could be quite helpful in this case.
What I am suggesting is creating a Circular doubly Linked List having a counter variable which keeps track of the index of each node and a static variable which will hold overall number of nodes in the list.

Now when you have a search item for the index which is greater than 50% of the total nodes count i.e. searching elements at lower half you can start traversing the list from reverse direction.

Let say you have 10 nodes in your circular linked list and  you want to search 8th node so you can quickly start traversing the list in opposite direction 2 times.

This approach reduces the iterations to search list item indexed at extremes but still in worst case you have to traverse half way through list for items in middle.

The only downfall in this approach is memory constraints which I am assuming is not an design concern here.